# Can't use ironpdf library in MVC Portlet

Tags: maven, bundle, portlet, liferay-7, spring-portlet-mvc

I am trying to create an MVC Portlet in which the ironpdf library is used to extract an image from a pdf and from a word document. The project is a maven project, I have included the library and its dependencies in the pom, but it is an infinite loop, every time I include some more, it asks me for another one. In addition to including it in the pom, I've included it in the bnd.bnd, as includeresources. Can you help me to be able to import it?

The last error it shows me is:
Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.google.api_ [Sanitized]

I am trying to use the ironpdf library to be able to extract images from pdf documents.